# OpenOffice.org calc: how to dynamically update a data range for a graph?

Tags: charts, openoffice-calc

I have an OpenOffice.org spreadsheet that contains a number of graphs. As I append more data to this spreadsheet, I want to update all the data ranges in those graphs, basically changing `A1:A100` to `A1:A101`, then to `A1:A102` and so on…

This is a borig manual work. Is there a way to automatize it with some clever trick? For example, can I use `INDIRECT()` function in data range definition?

Comment: I'm interested in the same topic, for OpenOffice.org ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it cannot be done in Calc. This feature is on the TODO list for the 3.x version. Calc is not able to ignore empty cells. When this feature is added, you can select the entire column or a wider range and ask Calc to ignore empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be workable for all graphs, but this is a 'trick'.

You might use the last row as a sentinel (that contains the same data as the row above; e.g. at A101 =OFFSET(A101,-1,0,1,1) etc).
Now you add your data above this 101 by inserting a row or number rows. Fill into the inserted number of rows your new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if this works in Calc, but I think it does (it does work in Excel): just select the entire columns as a source (`A:A`). Calc will ignore the empty cell's. When you add cell's, they will automatically be added to your graph.